# SUM and GROUP BY a substring in Splice (NoSql)

Tags: sql, nosql

I am trying to to run a query like the one below. The goal is to get the total activity count for every `user_key` but because the `user_key` has a complex structure and I need only the part after the '|' symbol I had to use a substring function. However, when I'm trying to run the query, I get the
error:

```
SQL Error [42Y36]: Column reference 'USER_KEY' is invalid, or is part of an invalid expression.  For a SELECT list with a GROUP BY, the columns and expressions being selected may only contain valid grouping expressions and valid aggregate expressions.
```

The substring function works OK outside this query. Any workarounds for this problem? Using Splice Machine (NoSql)

```
SELECT 
    substr(user_key, instr(user_key,'|') + 1) AS new_user_key,
    SUM(
        CAST(
            activity_count AS INTEGER
        )
    ) AS Total
FROM
    schema_name.table_name
GROUP BY
 substr(user_key, instr(user_key,'|') + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your GROUP BY column needs to match the SELECT

```
SELECT 
    substr(user_key, instr(user_key,'|') + 1) AS new_user_key,
    SUM(
        CAST(
            activity_count AS INTEGER
        )
    ) AS Total
FROM
    schema_name.table_name
GROUP BY
    substr(user_key, instr(user_key,'|') + 1) AS new_user_key
```

Comment: That did not work. It is not allowed to add aliases to GROUP BY expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself. I used a table subquery:

```
SELECT new_table.new_user_key, sum(new_table.total)
from
    (
    SELECT
        substr(user_key, instr(user_key,'|') + 1) AS new_user_key,
        CAST(activity_count AS INTEGER) AS Total
    FROM  schema_name.table_name
    )
    as new_table
GROUP BY
 new_table.new_user_key
```

Let's hope someone will find this post useful and will save some time to him or her.